# Running go program unit test on IDEA has encountered problems

Tags: unit-testing, go, intellij-idea

I'm using IDEA's golang plugin to develop an application. Before that, it worked fine, but since I updated golang to 1.3, when I run unit tests, my program receives a non-existing program parameter. Then there is panic: "flag provided but not defined: -test.v" This causes the unit program to fail.
How to make the program run normally, I don't want to change the original code, is there any other way to fix the error?

1. Update the IDEA version to 2019.2.1
2. Use IDEA golang version
   All of the above attempts failed

Here are some commands for IDEA unit test execution.

```
D:\go\bin\go.exe test -c -o xxxx.exe package_name #gosetup
D:\go\bin\go.exe tool test2json -t xxxx.exe -test.v -test.run ^function_name$ --debug #gosetup
```